# Visited link not identified correctly

Tags: css

I have a site I designed for a client which is primarily used by the visually impaired and adults with learning disabilities.

For some reason the client is reporting that when a link in the navigation is visited it is not identified despite the CSS being coded to change colour for a visited link. I have tried it in a few browsers but have been unable to re-create the issue.

Is their an issue with visited links in CSS3?

I am beginning to think it might just be a local issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could really do with some more info on this or maybe some code examples.

But, if your customer is using Safari on a Mac the issue may be as a result of this:

http://www.evotech.net/blog/2010/06/safari-5-link-selector-bug/

Comment: Yeah, this particular customer does use a Mac. I just downloaded Safari for Win7 and was finally able to see what the customer was talking about. Thanks for you help.